# Performance - TTL vs Deleting a row in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

We have a massive set of data that is written in to millions of rows in cassandra. We also have a scheduler that needs to process these records and remove them after processing them successfully.

Was wondering if Deleting the row after processing vs Marking a row with a TTL (essentially delaying its deletion).

Are there any pros / cons with Deletion vs TTL w.r.t Cassandra performance ?.

Thanks much
_DD

Comment: Well, my opinion is based just on observation of our system, but it seems to me that TTL should be better for perfomance. We use TTL a lot and there are no performance problems. However, sometimes we run manual cleaning jobs and these cause heavy load of our system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what little information you have given here it sounds to me that you are using Cassandra as a queue which is a well known anti-pattern.  You can read more about that here:

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-like-datasets

However to answer your basic question there is little difference in performance between using TTL and deletes.  TTL's in C* are handled as tombstones which is the same as a delete.  The major difference is that a tombstone is not written to a record who's TTL has expired until that record is read again.  When a delete is called a tombstone is immediately created.  Tombstones in general cause significant performance problems within C* and while there are some methods to mitigate the issues that they create having large numbers of them usually point to a poor data model or poor use case for C*.  If you are really looking at using C* as a queue why not look at using something more fit for that purpose such as Redis?

Comment: Thanks for the note bechbd - yes I am aware of this anti-pattern. Unfortunately we don't want to rely on another data source - due to resource constraints. Back to your point - "The major difference is that a tombstone is not written to a record who's TTL has expired until that record is read again"  - does that mean in case we don't visit this record - this stays  in the db ?. Please elaborate

Comment: No it will still be removed as part of the compaction process.  What I meant by this is that an additional tombstone record will not be written unless the TTL'd record is read.

Answer (score 5):

When using TTL the record is not removed from storage immediately, it is marked as tombstone. It gets physically removed only when the compaction occurs. Till that time the data impacts the nodes processing as it consumes the resources till the compaction happens. When you do a range query event the deleted(marked as tombstone) records are scanned by Cassandra. So using TTL to delete too many entries is considered as anti-pattern. The recommendation is to use temporary tables so that individual rows need not be removed. Just drop the entire table.

Comment: What If I use a range query for only range is not including tombstones?
Is it also scan tombstone records? Although the key has secondary index?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I've read, TTL will probably be as fast as your fastest delete process could be.  The reason for this is that TTL doesn't have to seek the data in order to mark it with a tombstone.  The TTL lives on the record and when the record is read and the TTL has expired, then it is marked with a tombstone.

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_expire_c.html