# Cassandra : TTL vs dynamic tables vs large amount of deletes

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have basically a `data` table like that (a partition `id`, along with a serialized value `serialized_value`) :

```sql
CREATE TABLE keyspace.data (
    id bigint,
    serialized_value blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) WITH caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
  AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.LeveledCompactionStrategy', 'enabled': 'true'}
    AND compression = { 'class' : 'LZ4Compressor'};
```

The usecase involves to maintain multiples versions of the data (`serialized_value` for a given `id`).

Every day, I will have to sent into Cassandra a fresh version of the data. It involves 100 millions of rows/partitions each time.

Of course, I don't need to maintain ALL version of the data, only the last 4 days (so the four most recent `version_id`).

**I identify three solutions to do that :**

**solution 1 : TTL**

the idea is to set a TTL at insert time. In that a way, oldest versions of the data are automatically dropped, without having problems related to thombstones.

> pros :
>
> - no read performance penalty (?)
> - no problem related to thombstones
>
> cons :
>
> - if fails occur with ingestion several days, I may loose all the data from the Cassandra cluster because of TTL automatic delete

**solution 2 : dynamic tables**

the table creation becomes :

```sql
CREATE TABLE keyspace.data_{version_id} (
    id bigint,
    serialized_value blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ...;
```

the table name include the `version_id`.

> pros :
>
> - the table (corresponding to a version) is easy to delete
> - no read performance penalty
> - no problem related to thombstones

> cons :
>
> - dynamically adding a table to the cluster might need all the nodes to be up every time.
> - a bit more difficult to handle client side (query specific table name, instead of the same one)

**solution 3 : large amount of deletes**

in that case, all the data stay in a single table, and a `version_id` is added to the primary key.

```sql
CREATE TABLE keyspace.data (
    version_id int,
    id bigint,
    serialized_value blob,
    PRIMARY KEY ((version_id,id))
) ...;
```

> pros :
>
> - only one single table to create and maintain, for the entire application lifecycle
>
> cons :
>
> - read performance penalty may occurs because of lot of thombstones
> - problem related to thombstones, because large amount of data need to be deleted, in order to purge all data related to old version_id.
>
> the delete will only match the exact partition key, so it will generate `partition  thombstones` and NOT `cell thombstones`. but thus, I'm afraid of the performance of doing that..

**What is the best way for you to acheive that ? :-)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be preferable to cluster your data based on a date or timestamp sorted in reverse order and still with TTL set. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE ks.blobs_by_id (
    id bigint,
    version timestamp,
    serialized_value blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, version)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (version DESC)
```

If you have a default TTL on the table, older versions will automatically expire so when you retrieve the rows with:

```
SELECT ... FROM blobs_by_id WHERE id = ? LIMIT 4
```

Only the 4 most recent rows will be returned (in descending order) and you won't be iterating over the deleted rows. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Erick. Thanks. But, i'm not sure to understand. In your example `version` is a clustering key. However, in my use case, the data will always be accessed by a particular version, AND a particular id (no iteration/range at all). So it is better to have `PRIMARY KEY ((id, version))` instead of `PRIMARY KEY (id, version)` which involve clustering, isn't it ?

Comment: In anycase, you choose the **solution 1**, based on TTL. However it will involve lot of thombstones, because all data related to a particular `version` will expire at once. In this SO post here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42862816/10098090), the author explicitly say that : **So using TTL to delete too many entries is considered as anti-pattern**. Do you agree with that ? *Because i'm in the exactly same situation..*

Comment: The author cited before also add that : **The recommendation is to use temporary tables so that individual rows need not be removed. Just drop the entire table.**. It seems a good idea to me (to go for the **solution 2** finally). However, I seen that other post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60510145/10098090) which say **Continuously creating and deleting number of tables in Cassandra is not a good practice and is never recommended**